Do questions need to be about design and/or specific problem solving?
I have been told that Electrical Engineering.SE is about design questions but while there is a specific design tag not all questions are tagged with design (much less circuit design). There are questions about optics, leds, optoelectronics
I have been told that the site is about solving a specific "problem" not about collating encyclopedic information.
How is What is LED starter? a design question, how is it about solving a specific problem; since the above question is on topic shouldn't I be able to ask about how a device works or how are 2 devices designed differently?

This is the third time you have asked about this topic, What is your object? Do you want us to tell you this is ok? Do you realize that you are creating a lot of work for the moderation team? Please stop asking questions about this topic that have already been answered, give it a rest. Also just because a question was not closed doesn't mean it is on topic

@VoltageSpike It was also upvoted (4 times more than it was downvoted). It also had a 9 times upvoted answer from a high reputation member. I want to understand the scope of the site. This above is not the only question that I can't see any specific problem to solve or any relation to design. I wanted a clarification on your answers and you denied me such clarification. If it is not covered in the answer probably my question wasn't as I intented. It has already been answered so my only venue is asking a new question about what I actually wanted to know.

The moderation system isn't 100% accurate. I can't speak to all past questions, but I can speak to future questions.

@VoltageSpike How condident are you on taliking about past questions? 99.9%? 99%? 95%? What habe the changes in the "moderation" been these past 3 weeks that you can speak about future questions? We digress, the question remains. I want to understand the scope of the site. How about any quesion not tagged design or circuit design?

Please check the help center, with the link that I sent in the first question. You can also search the other areas.

@VoltageSpike I have read the help center to the last iota carefully multiple times. But I don't understand what you mean search other areas.

@GeorgeNtoulos - The question indicates misconceptions about how Stack Exchange works & seems to be trying to force agreement with them. Also some comments are coming across (hopefully unintentionally) as confrontational, antagonistic and "rules lawyering", as if trying to catch out other people. || From experience, I have decided not to engage with this style of question. I see similar situations in your Meta questions on 2 other SE sites here & here. || I recommend avoiding that questioning approach.

@SamGibson I can't even conceive how Stack Exchange works. If anything there is more of a lack of "conception" than a misconception. What I want is to undestand the rules (and their underlying intent) that obviously includes why is X question allowed then (I am only asking because I don't understand the rules and their underlying intent at first hand, it seems that X question should also not be on topic). I am not trying to catch someone out (show that someone is doing wrong) in good faith I accept that there may be difference and I earnestly just want to understand what those differences are.

Design is a meta-tag - general enough that it's not helpful

@ScottSeidman What do you mean meta-tag? What I want to understand is if it is necessary for every question in Electrical Engineering.SE to be "design questions" how is a Design question different from a question that (at least) should (could) have the design question?  Doesn't that mean that every question without the tag either a) could/should have the tag or b )is of topic?

A meta tag is a tag that would apply to so many questions that it's useless as a search term.  Picture searching for "electronics" here.  "Design" isn't much better.

@ScottSeidman What about question needing to be about design? It implies that it should apply to all on topic questions (not just many but every question).

I made a comment about a specific point.  I didn't provide an answer, nor is any user required to.

@ScottSeidman Neither is any user prohibited from asking for clarifications about a comment about a specific point -and its relevance to the question-. While it is true that the tag can apply to many questions I can't see it apply to every question. That doesn't make many questions of topic.

The only person that's said "every" is you.

@ScottSeidman And I didn't imply that you or anyone else said the word. But I am trying to understand This is a site about electrical design questions. Unless "every" is used I don't understand the unfair discrimination.

"I don't understand the unfair discrimination." This website is largely managed by the community, and not by a central authority. Therefore, some off-topic questions might slip through, or even garner upvotes. It is nothing personal if your off-topic question is closed (and others are not).

@Velvet The meta site has literally a discussion tag. Some is not the same with several and much less a good-proportion (I am refering to every question that can't be tagged with design a good 15% at least)

Rules can only give a condensed and approximate synopsis about which of all possible questions are on-topic. And rules leave grey zones. Grey zones also evolve. Lawyerism certainly is inappropriate to try and sketch an exact "ontopicness threshold" in stackexchange. The ultimate arbiter is the moderation (including the community moderation).
If you ask grey zone questions, do anticipate that some, but not all, will be closed or downvoted.. This is not an issue, but will eventually guide you to an understanding of what people in a specific stackexchange want and what they don't want.


Do questions need to be about design and/or specific problem solving?

The scope is supposedly this one - What topics can I ask about here? Which is a rather brief and not the whole story. Examples of other types of questions not mentioned that are widely accepted here:

Component identification questions.
Electronics assembly questions.
Tool questions about EDA or simulators.

These are all closely related to electrical engineering though. Basically they are questions which some electrical engineers will be able to answer for sure.
As opposed to "How does device x work?" kind of questions, which isn't answerable by an electrical engineer but rather the electrical engineer who was involved in the design of that specific product or works in a specific niche of product development. It's no longer an electrical engineering question, but a "branch x" question. Like the "LED starter" question - it's a question asked to the branch of electrical indoor lighting products. So perhaps a better place to ask it would have been https://diy.stackexchange.com/ where you'll encounter lots of electrician users with hands-on experience of using these products.
Now as it happens, lots of electrical engineers have a nerdy interest in all things electronics, even when they don't work in that particular branch. So they may be able to answer it & find the question interesting still. Also, something simple and bare bones like this which appears just to essentially be a fuse is far easier to explain how it works than some complex electrical (sub)system product.
Common sense will get us very far - if a question can reasonably be answered by some electrical engineer with knowledge of the specific technology, it ought to be on topic, whereas questions that can only be answered by someone with knowledge of a specific product are probably not on-topic and likely better off at some site dealing with such products.
For example, not every EE is an expert of RF electronics. But some are and so RF questions are on-topic. But very few, if any, are experts about indoors lighting products - you'd have to be lucky to stumble upon someone who does. And so the question is no longer reasonable because it isn't interesting to the majority of the users and borderline off-topic.
Similarly, while discussing remote keys to cars, I could ask a theoretical RF electronics question at the car mechanics site and maybe with some luck there will be one or two users there who happen to also work with RF electronics. But for the vast majority of the user base there, such questions will be uninteresting and borderline off-topic.

I am not clear on what you mean with "product/device". Is LCD (not a specific panel but the engineering principles including physics, optics design of LCD as a whole) a product? How specifc is a product? I would use the term technology for that. There are no Microled or Nanoled Panels on the market (they are a topic for research, development, and maybe marketing). It is an Idea (Scientific, Abstract, Theoretics) there are no Implementations (I can't buy a panel nor was I referring to a specifc panel). I am not interested in using a panel that doesn't even exist. I want to undestand the idea.

@GeorgeNtoulos Again we'll have to use common sense: is something reasonably sold stand-alone (product) or is it pointless to sell it stand-alone and it is just a building block used during design (component). You can buy plenty of LCD as stand-alone products, but nobody buys a resistor for that purpose. By applying common sense we can also get the rough idea regarding if what we are asking is incredibly niche, like the behavior of future components still subject to research, or if it is reasonably something that at least some EE will have knowledge of.

And what it really boils down to isn't if the question is on-topic/off-topic but just if people visiting the site will find it interesting, find it a topic they expect to see on the site and consequently if it is a question you have any chance of actually receiving an answer about. There's no point in having an incredibly broad scope if that just results in boring (to the majority) niche questions that nobody knows the answer to anyway. Better then for everyone to ask such questions in the relevant forum where people are interested in them and actually able to answer them.

I got comments ranging from -A search appears to indicate it's different terminology for the same thing- to -You can clearly see the difference just by looking at the LED stages. One has single colour elements, the other shows a lot of little dots.-. Wouldn't an Electrical Engineer better explain the difference in the LED stages (do single elements imply that the entire band each colour is a single big element in Microled?)? [![picture][1]][1]  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/eNya09vI.png
